# how to fix laravel memcached write so much logs

Tags: ubuntu, memcached, sasl

### **I found my /var/log/syslog is over than 100GB**

**when i check the log i found memcached write all the log like below**

```
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27 Writing bin response:
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27   0x81 0x0d 0x00 0x17
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27   0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x20
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27   0x02 0xfd 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27 Read binary protocol data:
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27    0x80 0x0a 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27    0x02 0xfe 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: authenticated() in cmd 0x0a is true
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27 Writing bin response:
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27   0x81 0x0a 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27   0x02 0xfe 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: >27   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27 Read binary protocol data:
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27    0x80 0x0d 0x00 0x17
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x17
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27    0x02 0xff 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: <27    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Jul 31 06:20:14 skybtc-v3 systemd-memcached-wrapper[665]: authenticated() in cmd 0x0d is true
```

> i Used SASL with memcached

**how to fix it??**

Comment: not sure if Laravel has anything to do with this. It looks like a memcached configuration setting that has set too high a verbosity in logging

Comment: @apokryfos so how to fix this?